# How could I distribute my python program from my Mac to other machine?

Tags: python, setuptools

I made a program.

I had a Raspberry Pi and what I want to do is something like 'Create execution file of my Python program in Mac OS and pass it to Raspberry Pi(or my AWS) and run it'

What I did for this implementation is, just make whole project folder as `tar`  file and `scp` it to Raspberry pi and run it. But this is kinda cheesy.

I want to know most effective way to do this.

I heard things like `distutil`, `setuptools`, `pyscaffold` but there is no detailed example or tutorial on the web, even in Google, youtube. I mean, the contents are not enough for novice like me.

I think `pyscaffold` is really good tools, but it doesn't works well in my environment(Max OS X Elcapitan, Python 3.4)

I'd like to get some helpful advices about how to distribute your Python applications from all of you. Thanks.

Comment: Is your goal to simplify development, or to properly package it for a final release to end-users? Also, do you use Git?

Comment: Both are my goals, you know, "to properly package it for a final release to end-users" leads to "simplify development". Yeah. I also use a git. I want to know whether I use a git or other distribution tools and why.

Comment: [This](http://oddbird.net/set-your-code-free-preso/#/title) is one of the best guides I've seen to packaging. I find it useful having this setup, even if I don't release to PyPI, because you can use `pip` to install cleanly on any system, into virtual envs, etc. [This](https://github.com/agile-geoscience/striplog) project of mine follows the guide more or less to the letter.

Comment: Add to github, and clone to another computer. Create a setup file to use setuptools then `pip install --upgrade .` to install or upgrade it. I often do that~~